# mySQL Optimize Statement Groupby and Subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

i have a SQL Statement which looks like:

```
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(Name,id) as unqName from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(MP,id) as unqMP from (
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, concat(PIDs,",",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)) as PIDs, IFNULL(XT,id) as unqXT from ( 
select id, CIDs, COLOR, XT, MP, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id) as PIDs, IFNULL(COLOR,id) as unqCOLOR from Performance group by unqCOLOR 
) m group by unqXT 
) x group by unqMP 
) y group by unqName
```

i need to trim the Performance Details and get the PIDs, it works.
But i get duplicate PIDs (4 times), are there any Performance optimizations?
To get the SQL Statement faster executed and the PIDs unique?

```
mysql> select count(*) from Performance;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   243484 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Executed the SQL Statement takes:

```
Query OK, 137771 rows affected (43.54 sec)
```

SQLFiddle Link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b12/1/0

Comment: in the question is the sqlFiddle Link, there is an example ;)

Comment: yes that is the result i need, but PIDs should be unique and the statement execution time should be faster, any ideas?

Comment: In PIDs i need: 1,2 | 3 | 4,5

Comment: In short. I think it is possible to write quite a more effective query if you explain what you need from the input table you see on the left side of the fiddle. BTW, the group by you used are not correct: you can't predict the `id` you get in the result (do you really need the ID?)

Comment: yes because i could faster collect to data by id's

Comment: Explain how you need the output, the conditions need to satisfy and the calculations if any.